Why are my dispatched Livewire events delayed until the function finishes?
I have a Livewire component that uploads a video to YouTube in chunks. While uploading, I want to update the progress bar on the frontend by dispatching Livewire events for each chunk uploaded. However, the issue is that all the dispatched events are received only at the end of the function execution, instead of being received in real-time as the upload progresses. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Here’s a simplified example of my current implementation. The Component (YoutubeVideoUploader.php):
class YoutubeVideoUploader extends Component
{
    public function uploadVideo()
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $this->videoUploadProgress = $i;
            $this->dispatch('uploadProgress', ['progress' => $i]);
            Log::info("uploadProgress: " . $i . "%"); // this works well 
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}


Blade Template (youtube-video-uploader.blade.php):
<form id="videoUploadForm" wire:submit.prevent="uploadVideo">
    <!-- some fields here and a submit button -->
</form>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:init', () => {
        Livewire.on('uploadProgress', event => {
            const progress = event[0]?.progress ?? 0;
            // init hours, minutes, seconds..
            console.log(`[${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}] uploadProgress event:`, progress);
        });
    });
</script>


I'm really curious to know what's going on here too.

If important - I'm running this on Xampp on Windows and PHP 8.

All the dispatched events are sent to the frontend together with the response when the backend script finishes. This is how Livewire typically works

@c0dehunter the isolate attribute might be worth looking at - https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/bundling

IMO, every time you invoke sleep(1) in your uploadVideo method, PHP will halt the execution of the currently running script for 1 second.
The frontend will not receive the dispatched events in that time, so it seems events are buffered and fire all at once at the end of function execution.
Try to Force Livewire and PHP to flush the data to the frontend by using ob_flush() and flush() while the script is still running.
....
Log::info("uploadProgress: " . $i . "%");            
 ob_flush();
 flush();
 sleep(1);
....

